# Python. Асинхронность. Цепочки вызовов

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio

```
import asyncio

class a :
    async def m1(self) :
        # await...
        return self
    async def m2(self) :
        # await...
        return self
    async def m3(self) :
        # await...
        print(1)

async def s() :
    A = a()
    await A.m1().m2().m3()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(s())

# -----------------------------

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'm3'
```

Возможно ли как-то такое реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вызвать в цепочке можно так `await (await (await A.m1()).m2()).m3()` Выглядит жутко, но работает. Сделать именно так, как вам хочется, наверняка можно, но не стандартными средствами, насколько мне известно.

**UPDATE:**
Мне стало интересно и я накидал вариант

```
import asyncio
import random

class A:
    async def m1(self):
        print('TEST 1 BEGIN')
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        print('TEST 1 END')

    async def m2(self):
        print('TEST 2 BEGIN')
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        print('TEST 2 END')

    async def m3(self):
        print('TEST 3 BEGIN')
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        print('TEST 3 END')

    async def breaker(self):
        for x in range(3):
            await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
            print('KU-KU!')


class Chain:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.chain = []


    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attr = getattr(self.obj, name)
        if callable(attr):
            self.chain.append(attr)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Only methods can be chained!')
        return self


    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self


    async def execute(self):
        result = None
        for i in self.chain:
            if result:
                result = await i(result)
            else:
                result = await i()
        return result


async def main():
    a = A()
    futures = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(Chain(a).m1().m2().m3().execute()),
        asyncio.ensure_future(a.breaker())
    ]
    await asyncio.wait(futures)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Думаю, его можно развить до того, что вам нужно.

**UPDATE 2:**
Если к классу Chain добавить метод

```
def __await__(self):
    return self.execute().__await__()
```

то можно вызывать почти так, как и требовалось - `await Chain(a).m1().m2().m3()`

Comment: Интересная мысль! Правда нужно было иметь возможность передавать в методы аргументы, а не брать их из результата вызова предыдущего метода, но это легко исправить на самом деле. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выполнить несколько асинхронных методов по порядку один за одним (следующий метод не стартует, пока предыдущий не завершится):

```
o = await o.m1()
o = await o.m2()
o = await o.m3()
```

[Как показал @Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503351/23044), легко определить такой `Chain` класс, чтобы можно было писать:

```
await Chain(o).m1().m2().m3()
```

В реальном коде имена методов обычно длиннее и поэтому оба подхода должны быть одинаково читаемы. Первый подход более явный (и поэтому может быть яснее что происходит).

Подобный **fluent interface следует использовать крайне умеренно в Питоне** (код на Питоне как правило следует несовместимому [Command–query separation принципу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)) и [посмотреть нет ли лучшей более идиоматичной альтернативы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3884092/4279) в каждом конкретном случае. В тех случаях когда подобное API оправдано, желательно *возвращать неизменяемые объекты* из подобных методов, например, как это делает [Query API в SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html).

Если уже есть список coroutines, то можно обычный `for`-цикл использовать, чтобы выполнить их последовательно:

```
for coro in [asyncio.sleep(1) for _ in range(3)]:
    await coro
```

Код исполняется 3 секунды, не смотря на то что все coroutines создаются сразу (предсказуемо), то есть каждый вызов ожидает окончания предыдущего.

Для сравнения, вот код, выполняющийся за ~1 секунду (все функции исполняются одновременно):

```
await asyncio.wait([asyncio.sleep(1) for _ in range(3)])
```

Если есть список асинхронных методов, то чтобы выполнить их последовательно, передавая результат предыдущих вызовов в последующие, снова можно обычный цикл использовать:

```
obj = C()
for method in [C.m] * 3:
    obj = await method(obj)
```

В некоторых случаях, когда все методы с одним объектом работают и их смысл вернуть следующий доступный результат, можно использовать [`async for`-цикл](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-for):

```
async for line in reader:
    print('>>>', line)
```

где `reader` это объект реализующий [`__aiter__()`](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-iterable).